# Streamline C# code to make it easier to manage

Tags: c#

How would I streamline the below code to make it easier to manage over time?

```
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            remainTxt.AppendText("1");
        }
        else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            totalTxt.AppendText("1");
        }
        else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            paidTxt.AppendText("1");
        }
    }

    private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            remainTxt.AppendText("2");
        }
        else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            totalTxt.AppendText("2");
        }
        else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            paidTxt.AppendText("2");
        }
    }

    private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            remainTxt.AppendText("3");
        }
        else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            totalTxt.AppendText("3");
        }
        else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            paidTxt.AppendText("3");
        }
    }

    private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            remainTxt.AppendText("4");
        }
        else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            totalTxt.AppendText("4");
        }
        else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            paidTxt.AppendText("4");
        }
    }

    private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            remainTxt.AppendText("5");
        }
        else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            totalTxt.AppendText("5");
        }
        else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            paidTxt.AppendText("5");
        }
    }

    private void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            remainTxt.AppendText("6");
        }
        else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            totalTxt.AppendText("6");
        }
        else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            paidTxt.AppendText("6");
        }
    }

    private void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            remainTxt.AppendText("7");
        }
        else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            totalTxt.AppendText("7");
        }
        else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            paidTxt.AppendText("7");
        }
    }

    private void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            remainTxt.AppendText("8");
        }
        else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            totalTxt.AppendText("8");
        }
        else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            paidTxt.AppendText("8");
        }
    }

    private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            remainTxt.AppendText("9");
        }
        else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            totalTxt.AppendText("9");
        }
        else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            paidTxt.AppendText("9");
        }
    }

    private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            remainTxt.AppendText("0");
        }
        else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            totalTxt.AppendText("0");
        }
        else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            paidTxt.AppendText("0");
        }
    }

    private void btndot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            remainTxt.AppendText(".");
        }
        else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            totalTxt.AppendText(".");
        }
        else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            paidTxt.AppendText(".");
        }
    }

    private void btnback_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            remainTxt.Text = remainTxt.Text.Remove(remainTxt.Text.Length - 1, 1);
        }
        else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            totalTxt.Text = totalTxt.Text.Remove(totalTxt.Text.Length - 1, 1);
        }
        else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            paidTxt.Text = paidTxt.Text.Remove(paidTxt.Text.Length - 1, 1);
        }
    }

    private void btnreset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            remainTxt.Text = "";
        }
        else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            totalTxt.Text = "";
        }
        else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            paidTxt.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Questions about working code are better posted to codereview.stackexchange.com. (But try to extract the essence of your question and see if there is already a question like it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the logic into a separate method:

```
private void AppendValue(string valueToAppend)
{
    if(remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
    {
        remainTxt.AppendText(valueToAppend);
    }
    else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
    {
        totalTxt.AppendText(valueToAppend);
    }
    else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
    {
        paidTxt.AppendText(valueToAppend);
    }
}
```

Then call it from each click event:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AppendValue("1");
}
```

This should work for all your cases, except the `btnback_Click` event, but then you can just handle that method by itself without calling `AppendValue`.

Comment: How would that work with the last few methods, where no `AppendText()` gets called?

Answer (score 1):

As Grant writes, move similar logic into reusable methods. You could even use a single event handler and send in the value as a CommandArgument.

Secondly, never write business rules that depend on some form of UI component, like a color. Colors will more than likely change over time and the code will break. Instead, add some other field(s) for keeping the form state

Answer (score 1):

Define an action type as an enum, which can be extended in the future:

```
enum TextAction
{
    Clear,
    Append,
    RemoveLast
}

private void FormatText(TextAction action, string value = null)
{
    var textBox = DetermineTextBox();

    if (textBox != null)
    {
        switch (action)
        {
            case TextAction.Append :
                textBox.Text = value;
                break;
            case TextAction.Clear:
                textBox.Text = "";
                break;
            case TextAction.RemoveLast:
                textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Remove(textBox.Text.Length - 1, 1);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

private TextBox DetermineTextBox()
{
    if (remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
    {
        return remainTxt;
    }
    else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
    {
        return totalTxt;
    }
    else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
    {
        return paidTxt;
    }

    return null;
}

private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormatText(TextAction.Append, "1");
}

private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormatText(TextAction.Append, "2");
}

private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormatText(TextAction.Append, "3");
}

private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormatText(TextAction.Append, "4");
}

private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormatText(TextAction.Append, "5");
}

private void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormatText(TextAction.Append, "6");
}

private void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormatText(TextAction.Append, "7");
}

private void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormatText(TextAction.Append, "8");
}

private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormatText(TextAction.Append, "9");
}

private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormatText(TextAction.Append, "0");
}

private void btndot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormatText(TextAction.Append, ".");
}

private void btnback_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormatText(TextAction.RemoveLast);
}

private void btnreset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormatText(TextAction.Clear);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Switch statements, they will make it considerably cleaner...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx

Comment: Don't really see how this is a useful answer.

Comment: Don't really see how that's a useful response. Rather unconstructive IMO. OP is asking for code review, personally my only real suggestion would be to make it more readable using a switch statement.

Comment: How would a switch statement help? It's fairly obvious the OP is new, so saying "use a switch" is really vague. The correct answer would be to abstract the functionality out into another method that each handler would call. Not "using a switch".

Comment: Without seeing the form design it would be entirely based on speculation, thus very difficult to determine how to go about it. I did actually draw up a few lines of code, before realising this, and decided to be slightly more subtle in my response.

Comment: Completely ignored the fact that every if statement is identical. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
private var conditionColor = Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162);

private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckAndUpdateTextFields("1");
}

private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckAndUpdateTextFields("2");
}

private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckAndUpdateTextFields("3");
}

private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckAndUpdateTextFields("4");
}

private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckAndUpdateTextFields("5");
}

private void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckAndUpdateTextFields("6");
}

private void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckAndUpdateTextFields("7");
}

private void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckAndUpdateTextFields("8");
}

private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckAndUpdateTextFields("9");
}

private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckAndUpdateTextFields("0");
}

private void btndot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckAndUpdateTextFields(".");
}

private void btnback_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (remainTxt.BackColor == conditionColor)
    {
        remainTxt.Text = remainTxt.Text.Remove(remainTxt.Text.Length - 1, 1);
    }
    else if (totalTxt.BackColor == conditionColor)
    {
        totalTxt.Text = totalTxt.Text.Remove(totalTxt.Text.Length - 1, 1);
    }
    else if (paidTxt.BackColor == conditionColor)
    {
        paidTxt.Text = paidTxt.Text.Remove(paidTxt.Text.Length - 1, 1);
    }
}

private void btnreset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckAndUpdateTextFields("");
}

private CheckAndUpdateTextFields(string textToAppend)
{
   if(remainTxt.BackColor == conditionColor)
   {
       remainTxt.AppendText(textToAppend);
   }
   else if (totalTxt.BackColor == conditionColor)
   {
       totalTxt.AppendText(textToAppend);
   }
   else if (paidTxt.BackColor == conditionColor )
   {
       paidTxt.AppendText(textToAppend);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First define a method that accepts a delegate with the action you want to perform:

```
static void DoEventually(Action<T> action) where T: TextBox
{
    if(remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
    {
        action(remainTxt);
    }
    else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
    {
        action(totalTxt);
    }
    else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
    {
        action(paidTxt);
    } 
}
```

then you can call it along these lines:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoEventually(txt => txt.AppendText("1"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would encapsulate the rules for mapping a button index and a background-color to an string to a append in a separate class (or even bettern an interface). This could look like this:

```
public class ColorRules
{
    private IEnumerable<ColorRuleEntry> _rules;

    public ColorRules()
    {
        _rules = InitialColorRules();
    }

    private IEnumerable<ColorRuleEntry> InitialColorRules()
    {
        yield return new ColorRuleEntry(1, Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162), "1");
        yield return new ColorRuleEntry(2, Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162), "2");
        yield return new ColorRuleEntry(3, Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162), "3");
        yield return new ColorRuleEntry(4, Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162), "4");
        // and so on
    }

    public bool TryGetResult(int button, Color backgroundColor, out String result)
    {
        var entry = _rules.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Button == button && e.Color.Equals(backgroundColor));
        if (entry == null)
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }

        result = entry.Result;
        return true;
    }

    protected class ColorRuleEntry
    {
        public ColorRuleEntry(int button, Color color, String result)
        {
            Button = button;
            Color = color;
            Result = result;
        }

        public Color Color { get; protected set; }
        public int Button { get; protected set; }
        public String Result { get; protected set; }
    }
}
```

The usage of this class would then be like the following:

```
private ColorRules _rules = new ColorRules();

private void updateTextFormBackgroundColors(int buttonNr)
{
    var result = String.Empty;

    if (_rules.TryGetResult(buttonNr, remainTxt.BackColor, out result))
       remainTxt.AppendText(result);

    if (_rules.TryGetResult(buttonNr, totalTxt.BackColor, out result))
       totalTxt.AppendText(result);

    if (_rules.TryGetResult(buttonNr, paidTxt.BackColor, out result))
       paidTxt.AppendText(result);
}

private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    updateTextFormBackgroundColors(buttonNr: 4);
}
```